# Regression with an array instead of column as features in R

Tags: arrays, r, deep-learning, logistic-regression, decision-tree

I would like to know if it is possible to do a regression with features that will be in a single column and how to do it.

Example. Let's say my dataset is like this:

```
my_dataset <- data.frame(users=c(1,1,1,2,2),
                         items=c('A','B',"C","A","D"),
                         target=c(0,0,0,1,1))
```

output:

[image]

I know that usually to do any type of regression with need to transpose the column to have one row per customer with features as column like this

```
normal_dataset <- data.frame(users=c(1,2),
                             A =c(1,1),
                             B =c(1,0),
                             C= c(1,0),
                             D= c(0,1),
                             target=c(0,1)
                             )
```

[image]

But i am wondering if there is model that can consume  directly the first dataframe my_dataset without having to transpose as it requires data manipulation but also a lot of data manipulation

I was thinking of maybe something that keep all the data in one row but concatenated like this

```
library("dplyr")
maybelikethis <-  my_dataset %>%
  group_by(users) %>%
  summarise(item_list = paste(items, collapse = ' '),
            target = sum(target)) %>% 
      mutate(target = ifelse(target >0,1,0))
```

[image]

I am open to any suggestions

Comment: It would help to know what exactly is *items*. Your very simplified post is not too helpful. If this field is a single factor (e.g., household_id) column, you would not reshape wide but keep long. But if field holds multiple metrics (e.g., age, gender, race, income), then you would reshape wide.

Comment: Sorry for confusion , I thought it was clear that it is a single factor as  items is a single column on the example. but in the future i would have many factors that would be separated into many column. The question is not too much to know if we can keep it long or wide but it's to understand if there is a model that takes in input transaction data and is able to  understand that the multiple rows belong to the same customer. So basically is their a model that can consume long data directly and give the same output as if we used wide format

Comment: *But i am wondering if there is model* ... asking about model specification is off-topic on StackOverflow as we help with non-working code. Consider asking model-specific questions on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). But be sure to be specific on use case: exactly what your data entails and what you are trying to model.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the advices

Answer (score 1):

We can use `spread` here

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
my_dataset %>%
   mutate(n = 1) %>% 
   spread(items, n, fill = 0)
#.  users target A B C D
#1     1      0 1 1 1 0
#2     2      1 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: thanks Akrun, but I think my questions wasn't very clear. I am not asking how we can reshape the data so it is transpose ( i do know how to do it via reshape) . I am more asking if there is way or a model that consume long data ( and understand that the customer is the same) rather then wide data ( which force us to reshape it